# Dynamic pricing models in freight transportation (logistics) business

Tags: machine-learning, machine-learning-model

I'm not sure this could be an appropriate question for here.

I'm a newbie in the field of data science. 
I'm looking for keywords which can guide me to search the results to implement what I want to achieve.

Here are brief requirements that I want to implement.

- I'm developing and maintaining digital logistics platform in which we
  mainly be given freight transportation orders from clients and find
  right freight carrier to deliver the freights with proper fare (e.g., Uber Freight).
- To decide how much the fare is appropriate in terms of finding carriers on right time and maximize our revenue.
- Based on our years of working experience, the fare of freight transportation is affected by lots of factors such as 'the distance between load place and unload place', 'the weight and size of the freights', 'seasons', 'the time of transportation (night transportation fare is higher than day)', 'the carrier(driver)'s preferences of load/unload places' and etc.
- We have lots of data that contains final fare and factor variables to use for dynamic pricing.

What I want to ask is some keywords to research modeling techniques or methodologies to approach.

If the question is inappropriate then please let me know to revise the questions.

Thank you very much in advance.